# Confusing CSS - can anyone explain

Tags: css

I understand the dot in css is class but what is `h2` dot `h1` supposed to be selecting in the following I have found in a page?

```
h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 32px;
}
h2.h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.title.title_size_medium h1 {
  font-size: 38px;
  line-height: 38px;
}
```

The `h1` tag itself is never used in the page.

Many Thanks

Comment: It means select `h2` tag with the `.h1` class. If the `.h1` class is never used, it won't be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h2.h1` is selecting an `h2` element with the class `h1`:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: red;
}

h2.h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: blue;
}

.title.title_size_medium h1 {
  font-size: 38px;
  line-height: 38px;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<h1>Just an h1 element</h1>
<h2 class="h1">h2 element with the class "h1"</h2>

<div class="title title_size_medium">
  <h1>An h1 element inside a div with the class "title" and "title_size_medium"</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

h2.h1 selects the `<h2>` tags in your html, and the `.h1` css class styles the h2 tag with the styles from the h2 css class.